# Calculating topological $K(X)$ for complex projective manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, characteristic-classes

In the introduction to the book Vector bundles and K-theory

[http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html)

two approaches to classification of (topological) vector bundles are discussed - the topological $K$-theory and Characteristic classes. Having algebraic geometry in mind, characteristic classes are omni-present when one deals with complex projective manifolds (Grothendick-Riemann-Roch...). One computes them quite often. However I don't seem to remember calculations of the whole ring $K(X)$ in books on algebraic geometry. So I wonder, do people compute (the topological) $K(X)$ for complex projective manifolds? And if they do, in which circumstances and for which purpose?

Comment: Do you mean the topological $K(X)$ or the algebraic one? For the latter there is a huge literature, starting with SGA 6.

Comment: abx, I mean the topological $K(X)$. I corrected question, so that this is unambiguous

Comment: By the way also characteristic classes have a topological version and an algebraic version

Comment: The topological K-theory of complex projective spaces is computed here https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3959.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}[u,u^{-1}])\Longrightarrow K^*(X)$, in which the differentials are always torsion-valued.  Thus, if $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free, then the spectral sequence collapses, and $K^*(X)$ has a natural filtration whose associated graded ring is isomorphic to $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}[u,u^{-1}])$.  There are many complex projective varieties $X$ to which this applies.  Moreover, in these cases it is usually not hard to find explicit generators of the $K$-theory.  In particular, any complex vector bundle $V$ over $X$ has Chern classes $c^H_i(V)\in H^{2i}(X;\mathbb{Z})$ and also Chern classes $c^K_i(V)\in K^{2i}(X)$.  If we have a basis for $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z})$ consisting of monomials in cohomological Chern classes, then the corresponding monomials in $K$-theory Chern classes will give a basis for $K^*(X)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[u,u^{-1}]$.

Comment: Thank you! Would you advise some relatively accessible source on this matter?

Comment: I think Chern classes only live in even degree ones. How can we find a basis for odd degree cohomology consisting of monomials in Chern classes?

Comment: @Z.Liu I only claim that there is a large class of interesting examples where the cohomology is concentrated in even degrees ad admits a basis consisting of monomials in Chern classes.  There are of course other examples in which this is not the case.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Oh, yes. Sorry for the misunderstanding.